# bootstrap fonts blocked by CORS when using azure cdn with asp net core website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, fonts, cors, cdn

I am using an azure cdn to serve static files one of which being bootstrap.css.
So on my web page I have a link to

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href='//<cdn>/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)' crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

this loads correctly but within the bootstrap.css file there are references to font files. These are requested from my cdn endpoint like as follows

```
http://<cdn>/lib/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2'
Origin: http://<my website domain>
Referer: http://<cdn>/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

But still I get A CORS error

```
Access to Font at 'http://<cdn>/lib/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2' from origin 'http://<my website domain>' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://<my website domain>' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

I have CORS configured to always serve to any domain as follows

Startup.cs - ConfigureServices

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });
```

And in Startup.cs, Configure

```
 app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

The initial request to get the bootstrap.css returns a response header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://<my website domain>
```

As far as I can see it is setup correctly but it just does not seem to work
Any Ideas what I am doing wrong..?

Comment: If you look closely at your error message, you'll see *The response had HTTP status code 404.*. That's the issue you want to resolve - why is the font file 404ing?

Comment: I have verified that the font file definitely exists in the correct location. I think CORS blocks access to it causing a 404

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following to the webconfig?

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I'm using .net core running on Linux so there is no web.config. sorry i should have made that more clear